# ArcGIS - Retrieve all data from REST service in GeoJSON format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geojson, json

The great state of Vermont publishes a number of datasets in ArcGIS:

https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/OPENDATA_VCGI_UTILITIES_SP_NOCACHE_v1/MapServer

I can create a query for one of these layers that specifies some random filter, e.g., [OBJECTID!=1](https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/OPENDATA_VCGI_UTILITIES_SP_NOCACHE_v1/MapServer/3/query?where=OBJECTID%21%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=geojson). This returns GeoJSON, hurrah! However, what I want is the entire dataset (i.e., all features, all attributes), with no filters. Is there a way to query the data in a way that will return that?

Additionally, the SRID for this data is 32145. Is the output of the GeoJSON always in 4326, or do I have to specify that?

Comment: You could test for "1 =1", too, but you can't make a service return more than the maxFeatuers configured for the service (and scraping might be a TOS violation).

Comment: From [RFC 7946 - The GeoJSON Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946), "Note: the use of alternative coordinate reference systems was specified in [GJ2008](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#ref-GJ2008), but it has been removed from this version of the specification because the use of different coordinate reference systems -- especially in the manner specified in [GJ2008](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#ref-GJ2008) -- has proven to have interoperability issues."

Answer (score 0):

Install `esridump` via `pip`

Example to grab layer VT VEC Poles - point

Then execute

```
esri2geojson https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/OPENDATA_VCGI_UTILITIES_SP_NOCACHE_v1/MapServer/81 youroutput.geojson
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to my question, but I was able to use https://github.com/rowanwins/mapbox-gl-arcgis-featureserver for my use case